# HTML Email table Starting From bottom in Outlook Desktop

Tags: html, css, outlook, html-table, html-email

I am creating an Fluid html email. I have 2 table  inside parent table. The Left side of table has more content than the right side. Only in Outlook Desktop, the right side table is going to bottom. I ant right table to be aligned to top always. If I have less content on left side.  It works perfect. 
Below is the Sample HTML code :

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="100%" style="border-collapse: collapse;" >
    <tr>
        <td valign="top">
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="69%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td valign="top">
            <![endif]-->
            <table class="col535" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;max-width:535px;width:100%;border-right:1px solid #aaaaaa;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="left_column_stack" valign="top" style="padding:0 20px 0 0;vertical-align:top;">
                        // Very Long Text (1500 lines)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->

            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
            <table width="25%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td>
            <![endif]-->
            <table width="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" style="border-collapse:collapse;max-width:200px;width:100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td class="right_column" valign="top" style="padding:0 0 0 20px;" >
                        // Small Text (250 lines)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
            <![endif]-->
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

JS Fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/NrERK/

Note: Its only behaving odd Outlook Desktop. Elsewhere its working good. 
Please provide me any Solution.

Answer (score 0):

While making a HTML email it would be good if you use 'px' value instead of '%' value.

I have change the width of main table from 100% to 700px

Here's a [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/kheema/NrERK/3/)!

```
<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="700" style="border-collapse: collapse;" >
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="69%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
        <![endif]-->
        <table class="col535" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="left" style="float:left;border-collapse:collapse;max-width:500px;width:100%;border-right:1px solid #aaaaaa;">
            <tr>
                <td class="left_column_stack" valign="top" style="padding:0 20px 0 0;vertical-align:top;">
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>                  
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->

        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
        <table width="25%" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
        <![endif]-->
        <table width="200" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" align="left" style="float:left;border-collapse:collapse;max-width:200px;width:100%;">
            <tr>
                <td class="right_column" valign="top" style="padding:0 0 0 20px;" >
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>
                    Left Side <br>

                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <!--[if (gte mso 9)|(IE)]>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <![endif]-->
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for input. My Requirement was to have 100% width layout. I am aware of 550-650 px layouts for emailer. 
Right Now my query is regarding outlook desktop behaving wrongly for 2 tables. 
If you could provide solution to that ?

Comment: which version of outlook you are using?

Comment: It is Outlook 2010. But the issue is on from Outlook 07/10/13

Answer (score 0):

If you shorten your first column, does it fix the issue?

By what you are describing, this could be the Outlook page break issue. Here is [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21111579/outlook-renders-unnecessary-space/21146170#21146170)

It could also be a float (align) issue, it is hard to tell without seeing a screenshot.